# Error using  jQuery UI Selectmenu plugin in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

The jQuery UI Selectmenu plugin, demoed here: http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html

I am having a couple of problems with this plugin. I'll focus on just one that only happens in IE.

I have html:

```
<label for="SearchState"></label>
<select style="width: 160px" name="SearchState" id="SearchState">
   <option>CT</option>
   <option>MA</option>
   <option>NH</option>
</select>
```

and jQuery:

```
$('select#SearchState').selectmenu();
```

In Firefox this works, however in IE I get error on load:

> `"Invalid argument" - jquery 1.4.2 Line: 4618`

However the new styled selectmenu appears along with the original one (this is by design, but the original html select menu should be hidden), but when I click an option I get several of these errors:

> "this._optionList" is null or not an object - ui.selectmenu.js Line 400

Any ideas why this does not work in IE?

Lines 399-401 of ui.selectmenu.js

```
_selectedOptionLi: function() {
    return this._optionLis.eq(this._selectedIndex());
},
```

Lines 4615-4622 of jquery-1.4.1.js

```
name = name.replace(rdashAlpha, fcamelCase);

if ( set ) {
    style[ name ] = value;
}

return style[ name ];
```

Comment: Is the plugin you are using the latest version? If not, try upgrading it and upgrading jquery if you can

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer, you say you quoted an error from jquery 1.4.2 and then showed code from 1.4.1.  Which version are you including in your page?  Also which version of jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: Which version of jQuery, jQuery UI, selectmenu, IE, and Windows are you using? We just need some clarification.

Comment: Does my answer answer your question? Just don't want you to forget about the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

I confirmed this behavior. I recreated it in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TkPPZ/2/). After upgrading jQuery to 1.7.2, it did not give these errors. In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TkPPZ/3/) is the fixed version. Note that I also upgraded jQuery UI (because of jsFiddle) to jQuery UI 1.8.18, but the problems lie in the version of jQuery you are using. I recommend updating to the most recent (stable) version of [jQuery and jQuery UI](http://code.jquery.com/), and selectmenu ([JavaScript](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/blob/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js) and [CSS](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/blob/selectmenu/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectmenu.css)).

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old jQuery UI  **labs** plugin and it looks like it hasn't been worked on in a while.

Take a look at this fork on github https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui.

> A fork of jQuery UI to push development of some plug-ins. Currently you will find: the latest version of Selectmenu (originally by filament group) and a accessible version of jQuery UI Tabs. Please check branch selectmenu and tabs-accessibility

Answer (score 0):

If the demo you linked to works in IE, as a first step I would try using the [same version of selectmenu that the demo is](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/ui.selectmenu.js).  If this works, you know it is a problem with the plugin.